# Unicode Query in OpenRowSet

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, unicode, nvarchar, openrowset

I have a stored procedure with nvarchar parameters. i want to get returned table using OPENROWSET. but when i use following codes the results would be incorrect

```sql
Declare @ID int
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Declare @p1  nvarchar(8)
Set @ID=1
Set @sql='SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
    ''SQLNCLI'',
    ''DRIVER={SQL Server};'',
    ''EXEC dbo.usp_test @p1 =''''' + @p1 + ''''')'
Exec(@sql)
```

the OPENROWSET will convert my query to VARCHAR and doesn't execute my procedure correctly.
it seems that OPENROWSET execute my code like this:

```sql
exec dbo.usp_test @p1='????????'
```

so the results are incorrect. Is there any option in OPENROWSET to resolve my problem?

Comment: `Set @sql= N'SELECT *....` - does this work?

Comment: nope. your solution doesn't work

Comment: @sheykholeslam: Try `... @p1 = N''''' + ...`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `nvarchar` data you need to add a specific character (`N`) before your string values like this:

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @p1  nvarchar(8)
SET @ID=1
SET @sql = N'SELECT * 
             FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',
                          ''DRIVER={SQL Server};'',
                          ''EXEC dbo.usp_test @p1 = N''' + @p1 + N''''')'
EXEC(@sql)
```

> **NOTE :**
>   When you have `'''EXEC dbo.usp_test @p1 =''''' + 'p1' + ''''''` is equal to `'EXEC dbo.usp_test @p1 =''p1''` that is wrong and should be like `'''EXEC dbo.usp_test @p1 =''' + 'p1' + ''''''` for `'EXEC dbo.usp_test @p1 ='p1''`